# How to get the DialogPreference POSITIVE_BUTTON to work on OnClick?

Tags: java, android, events, mobile, onclick

I'm trying to write something to set a password with `DialogPrefence`.
How do I get the `onClick()` event at **OK** button from the dialog?

Here is the code:

```
package com.kontrol.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class SS1_Senha extends DialogPreference implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    public SS1_Senha(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.ss1_senha);

        setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //Action after OK

            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to implement the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and handle the `OnClick` events of each buttons

Create a custom `DialogPreference` class like this

```
public class CustomDialogPreference extends DialogPreference implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setPersistent(false);
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.image_dialog);
    setPositiveButtonText("OK");
    setNegativeButtonText("CANCEL");
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
    if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
        // do your stuff to handle positive button
    }else if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE){
        // do your stuff to handle negative button
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: setNegativeButtonText("CANCEL");

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you need to know about key pressed event in another classes (not in the SS1_Senha). For this you can use listeners (observers) pattern or handler.

Answer (score -1):

To show an alert dialog you  can use AlertDialog.builder.
For example:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AlertDialogActivity.this).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Dialog");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("My Message");


    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
```